# Compute $y'(-1)$ if $y(x)=f(\sqrt{|x|+3})$ and $f'(2)=-\frac13$

Tags: derivatives

let : $$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\frac{-1}{3}$$

and : $$y=f(\sqrt{|x|+3})$$

then :

$$\frac{d}{dx}y(-1)=?$$

My try :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\frac{-1}{3}=\frac{d}{dx}f(2) $$

Now : $$u(x):=\sqrt{|x|+3}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}\times \frac{dy}{du} $$

$$\frac{dy(-1)}{dx}=\frac{du(-1)}{dx}\times \frac{dy(-1)}{du} $$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\frac{x}{|x|}}{2\sqrt{|x|+3}}\to \frac{du(-1)}{dx}=\frac{-1}{4} $$

Now :
$$\frac{dy(-1)}{du}=?$$

Comment: $\frac{dy}{du}(-1)$ is given in the first line.

Comment: @Slade How... ?

Comment: @Slade Not quite, the denominator doesn't come out right.

Comment: You're actually almost there, observe that $\frac{dy}{du}$ is the $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}(-1)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{y(-1+h)-y(-1)}{h}
$$
by the definition of the derivative.  Then, substituting the formula for $y$ gives
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{y(-1+h)-y(-1)}{h}&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(\sqrt{|-1+h|+3}\right)-f\left(\sqrt{|-1|+3}\right)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(\sqrt{|-1+h|+3}\right)-f(2)}{h}
\end{align*}
Observe that as $h$ gets close to zero, $-1+h$ becomes negative, so $|-1+h|=1-h$ (when $h$ is sufficiently close to zero).  Therefore
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(\sqrt{|-1+h|+3}\right)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(\sqrt{4-h}\right)-f(2)}{h}
$$
Let $k=\sqrt{4-h}$.  Then, as $h$ approaches zero, $k$ approaches $2$.  Moreover, $h=4-k^2$.  Making this substitution, we have
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(\sqrt{4-h}\right)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{k\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(k)-f(2)}{4-k^2}.
$$
Factoring the denominator, we get
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(k)-f(2)}{4-k^2}=\lim_{k\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(k)-f(2)}{-(k-2)(k+2)}=\lim_{k\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(k)-f(2)}{k-2}\cdot\frac{1}{-k-2}
$$
We know that the limit of the first part is $-\frac{1}{3}$ and by substitution, we get the limit of the second part is $-\frac{1}{4}$, so the entire limit is $\frac{1}{12}$.

Answer (score 2):

The condition on $f$ is the definition of $f'(2) = -\frac{1}{3}$. In a neighborhood of $x = -1$, $|x| = -x$, so $y(x) = f(\sqrt{-x + 3})$ and you can find $y'(-1)$ with the chain rule: $$\begin{align*} y'(-1) &= \frac{d}{dx} f\left(\sqrt{-x + 3}\right) \\
&= \left. \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{-x + 3}\right|_{x=1} f'\left(\sqrt{-(-1) + 3} \right) \\
&= \frac{-1}{2 \sqrt{ - (-1) + 3}} f'(2) \\
&= \frac{-1}{4} \frac{-1}{3} = \frac{1}{12}\end{align*}$$

I'm assuming that you can use without proof the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$. If not, you can prove it yourself by differentiating both sides of the equation $x = (\sqrt{x})^2$, using the chain rule on the right, to get $1 = 2 \sqrt{x} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} \right)$.